# Kubuntu 18.04 add user writable ext4 partition from free space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, kubuntu

This should be an easy question, but I don't know the answer. I'm using a brand new Dell Inspiron (it's a 5770) with changes to booting and hard drives that Kubuntu 18.04 might not have planned for. It works. But I want an extra partition to store data on that I can write to with user permissions from the free space on the hard drive. The installer did it, but wouldn't let me use it. As I started getting into how to do it, GRUB treated it as an OS and put up a boot menu. I just want a little space to keep my files. It's back to free space again and the machine boots and runs normally. Minimal install. Defaults. No issues. KDE Partition Manager does not do the trick. I need the command line instructions, file names, permissions, etc. to simply make a user-writable partition with nothing in it from existing free space on a hot new machine running a hot new OS. It should still be an old-school Linux question. Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't KDE Partition Manager do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I ones read the remedy for your problem. To be very short:
sudo chgrp adm /media/user/namepartition

then:

sudo chmod g+w /media/user/namepartition

that's all!
(works after rebooting)